# ¿Cómo saber si el usuario quiere seleccionar el texto o moverlo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo esto:

JS:

```
var p = document.getElementById("p");
p.addEventListener("dragend", fp);
function fp(e){
  p.style.left=e.pageX+"px";
  p.style.top=e.pageY+"px"
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="p" draggable="true">texto movible</p>
```

Css:

```
#p{
   position:absolute;
}
```

Que lo que hace es mover el texto, el problema esque ahora tengo que hacer que también pueda ser seleccionable para que el usuario modifique estilo del texto. ¿Como puedo diferenciar entre cuando quiere mover texto o seleccionarlo? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas acciones se realizan manteniendo le botón del mouse presionado y moviéndolo de un lado a otro, por lo que creo que son funcionalidades excluyentes.

No queda más que implementar un mecanismo que permita ambas acciones, existen varias alternativas, a mi parecer la más fácil de implementar es tener 2 "modos":

- Modo mover -> draggable="true"
- Modo seleccionar -> draggable="false"

Y cambias de modo al hacer `dobleclick` en el elemento

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p");
p.addEventListener("dragend", fp);
p.addEventListener("dblclick", swap);
function fp(e){
  e.target.style.left=e.pageX+"px";
  e.target.style.top=e.pageY+"px"
}

function swap(e){
  e.target.draggable = !e.target.draggable;
}
```

```css
#p{
   position:absolute;
}
[draggable="true"]{
  outline:1px solid gray;
  outline-offset:2px;
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" draggable="true">texto movible</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Por curiosidad  cuáles podrían ser las otras alternativas?

Comment: @Microchip Las mas habitual es dejar un área para mover, tal como las ventanas en window tienen una área (la barra de arriba) o por ejemplo en joomla que hay un icono https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igUu.png. Lo otro que se me ocurre es usar otro botón del mouse o una tecla más el botón